# Convey ' cutting-edge' as an adjective and as a noun

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, technologie

**Cutting edge** as an adjective is used to describe the newest, most advanced version of a product or service. The phrase cutting edge has a positive connotation. As a noun , it implies the forefront of technological developments or advancements.

> The new company I work for is at the cutting edge of medical science. I think some of their new instruments are going to revolutionize the field of medicine.

> With their cutting-edge instruments, I really think this company is going to revolutionize the field of medicine.

I have seen turns like 'de pointe', 'nec plus ultra' but my native colleagues say that neither convey the meaning. In addition, a professor of FLE says that there is no equivalent French expression.

Comment: What is wrong with the translation given by most dictionaries? [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/cutting-edge), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/cutting-edge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not wrong because it's only equivalent to one definition of cutting-edge. We would use "de pointe" for the main definition. According to [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pointe/62009):

> (Expression)
>
> **De pointe, en pointe,** qui est à l'avant-garde du progrès, à son maximum d'évolution.

Definition of cutting-edge from Google:

> The latest or most advanced stage in the development of something.
>
> (x) A dynamic or invigorating quality.

For both of your examples, it would work. Note that it's used a lot less in French unless it's paired with "technology", so it might be a bit unusual but not incorrect. You cannot use it only for the second meaning though:

> The campaign began to lose its cutting edge.

You would have to use something like "avantage" or "avance" in this situation.

Comment: You didn't specify clearly how it would work for the first example. With "*de pointe*" it would be "*La nouvelle entreprise pour laquelle je travaille **est à la pointe** de la médecine*". Oh and I've never heard "*en pointe*" with that meaning.